# nav link active for webpages is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

hello i was preparing the sidebar and faced a problem. Problem is nav link is not getting active class when page is redirected to a page.If additional information is required ask me in comment section. but hope you understood it. I tried doing it, have a glance at my work and help me to rectify the mistake.

```js
const sidebar = document.querySelector('#mySidebar')

const toggle = document.querySelector('#sidebar-toggle')

toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleSidebar)

function toggleSidebar(e) {
  toggle.classList.toggle('open')
  sidebar.classList.toggle('open');
}
//for sidebar active class on page 
const activePage = window.location.pathname;
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-nav ul li a').
forEach(link => {
  if(link.href.includes(`${activePage}`)) {
    link.classList.add('active');
  }
})
//for sidebar active class on page
```

```css
*{
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
header{
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width:100%;
  background: coral;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 1001;
}
header img{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
#sidebar-toggle{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#sidebar-toggle div{
   width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
#sidebar-toggle.open .bar4 {
  transform: translate(0, 11px) rotate(-45deg);
}

#sidebar-toggle.open .bar5 {
  opacity: 0;
}

#sidebar-toggle.open .bar6 {
  transform: translate(0, -11px) rotate(45deg);
}

.sidebar-header img{
  width:30px;
}
.sidebar {
  display:none;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 41px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 15.625rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.open.sidebar {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar-header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}

.sidebar-header img {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 41px;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
  height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-header h6 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.sidebar-nav{
  margin:  0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li{
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    color:#007bff !important;
    padding:  5px 10px;
    margin: 1px 0;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 300!important;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .active,
.sidebar-nav ul .active a .icon{
    background:#007bff;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.sidebar-nav ul li:hover,
.sidebar-nav ul li:hover a .icon, 
.sidebar-nav ul li:hover a{
    background:#007bff;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li .icon{
  color:#007bff;
  width:30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.sidebar-nav .sidebar-nav-header{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: -0.75rem 1.5rem;
  color:#0c7db1;
}
.sidebar-nav ul ul{
  position: static;
  display: none;
}
.sidebar-nav ul ul li{
  line-height: 25px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul ul li a{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li a .caret{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 8px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li a:hover .caret{
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.sidebar-nav ul .sub-menu.show{
  display: block;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li a .caret .sub-menu.show{
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.sidebar-nav ul li span.number{
  float: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #007bff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500!important;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li:hover span.number{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/userupload/3158902/file/original-7c71bfa677e61dea61bc2acd59158d32.jpg?resize=400x0">
  <div id="sidebar-toggle">
    <div class="bar4"></div>
    <div class="bar5"></div>
    <div class="bar6"></div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="sidebar" id='mySidebar'>
  <div class="sidebar-container">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/0d/cf/b5/0dcfb548989afdf22afff75e2a46a508.jpg">
      <h6>Umann goswami</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>Home</a></li>
             
             <li><a href="feed"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i></span>Feed</a></li>

             <li class="caret"><a href="#"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-pen-nib"></i></span>Posts<span class="caret fas fa-angle-down">
             </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Blogs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Images</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>

             <li class="caret"><a href="#"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-pen-nib"></i></span>Posts<span class="caret fas fa-angle-down">
             </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Blogs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Images</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             
             
             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="far fa-bell"></i></span>Notifications</a><span class="number">14</span></li> 

             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i></span>Categories</a></li>


             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span>Settings</a></li>
        </ul>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="main">
    Welcome human
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like active is being added in the snippet. But you do have broken HTML with start spans but not closing them. Also, in your .active CSS for the icon I'm assuming **.sidebar-nav ul .active a .icon** should be **.sidebar-nav ul .active .icon** as active is being applied to the anchor